# Why won't my Do-while loop work to run the Menu in C++

Tags: c++, function, loops, menu, do-while

I know I am probably missing something obvious, but my code will only run the do loop in the main function once. After the selected function (with menu selection) is ran the program exits instead of restarting the loop. I am not sure what is wrong with my loop. Please Advise.

P.S. This program is written in C++

Here is the entire body of the program. All of the functions work with the exception of the do loop in the main function.

```
//It also includes functions to cancel a selection and to show all seats on the flight.

//These allow the predefined functions within the program to operate.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//This sets the namespace of the entire program to std
using namespace std;

//This creates a constant variable for the rows of seats on the flight.
const int rows = 13;

//This creates a constant variable for the seats in each row on the flight.
const int seats = 6;

//This line creates the array to store the seat assignments.
char flight[rows][seats];

//This function displays the seating chart for the flight
int display()
{
   cout << "Displaying the current seating assignments for the flight." << endl;
   cout << "The '*' symbol means the seat is available and 'X' means it is not." << endl;
   cout << "      A " << "B " << "C " << "D " << "E " << "F " << endl;
   for(int i=0; i < rows; i++)
   {
       cout << "Row " << i+1 << " ";

       for(int j=0; j < seats; j++)
       {
           cout << flight[i][j] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }


}

//This function allows the user to assign their seat.
int assign()
{
   int type;

   cout << "To begin making your seat assignment please select your ticket type." << endl;
   cout << "1. First Class" << endl;
   cout << "2. Business Class" << endl;
   cout << "3. Economy Class" << endl;
   cout << "Please select 1, 2, or 3 from the menu." << endl;

   cin >> type;

   int fcrow;
   string fcseat;

   if(type == 1)
   {
       cout << "You selected First Class" << endl;
       cout << "Please review available First Class Seats." << endl;

       cout << "      A " << "B " << "C " << "D " << "E " << "F " << endl;
       for(int f = 0; f < 2; f++)
       {
           cout << "Row " << f+1 << " ";

           for(int g = 0; g < seats; g++)
           {
               cout << flight[f][g] << " ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }

       cout << "Please enter in the desired row (1 or 2)" << endl;
       cin >> fcrow;

       cout << "Please enter in the desired seat (A-F)" << endl;
       cin >> fcseat;

       cout << "You selected Row " << fcrow << " Seat " << fcseat << endl;

       int fcsi;

       if(fcseat == "A")
       {
           fcsi = 0;
       }

       if(fcseat == "B")
       {
           fcsi = 1;
       }

       if(fcseat == "C")
       {
           fcsi = 2;
       }

       if(fcseat == "D")
       {
           fcsi = 3;
       }

       if(fcseat == "E")
       {
           fcsi = 4;
       }
       if(fcseat == "F")
       {
           fcsi = 5;
       }


       flight[fcrow-1][fcsi] = 'X';

       cout << "Displaying Updated Flight Seating Chart" << endl;

       return display();
   }

   int bcrow;
   string bcseat;

   if(type == 2)
   {
       cout << "You selected Business Class" << endl;
       cout << "Please review available Business Class Seats." << endl;

       cout << "      A " << "B " << "C " << "D " << "E " << "F " << endl;
       for(int h = 2; h < 7; h++)
       {
           cout << "Row " << h+1 << " ";

           for(int k = 0; k < seats; k++)
           {
               cout << flight[h][k] << " ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
       cout << "Please enter in the desired row (3-7)" << endl;
       cin >> bcrow;

       cout << "Please enter in the desired seat (A-F)" << endl;
       cin >> bcseat;

       cout << "You selected Row " << bcrow << " Seat " << bcseat << endl;

       int bcsi;

       if(bcseat == "A")
       {
           bcsi = 0;
       }

       if(bcseat == "B")
       {
           bcsi = 1;
       }

       if(bcseat == "C")
       {
           bcsi = 2;
       }

       if(bcseat == "D")
       {
           bcsi = 3;
       }

       if(bcseat == "E")
       {
           bcsi = 4;
       }
       if(bcseat == "F")
       {
           bcsi = 5;
       }


       flight[bcrow-1][bcsi] = 'X';

       cout << "Displaying Updated Flight Seating Chart" << endl;

       return display();
   }

   int ecrow;
   string ecseat;

   if(type == 3)
   {
       cout << "You selected Economy Class" << endl;
       cout << "Please review available Economy Class Seats." << endl;

       cout << "      A " << "B " << "C " << "D " << "E " << "F " << endl;
       for(int l = 7; l < rows; l++)
       {
           cout << "Row " << l+1 << " ";

           for(int m = 0; m < seats; m++)
           {
               cout << flight[l][m] << " ";
           }
           cout << endl;
       }
       cout << "Please enter in the desired row (8-13)" << endl;
       cin >> ecrow;

       cout << "Please enter in the desired seat (A-F)" << endl;
       cin >> ecseat;

       cout << "You selected Row " << ecrow << " Seat " << ecseat << endl;

       int ecsi;

       if(ecseat == "A")
       {
           ecsi = 0;
       }

       if(ecseat == "B")
       {
           ecsi = 1;
       }

       if(ecseat == "C")
       {
           ecsi = 2;
       }

       if(ecseat == "D")
       {
           ecsi = 3;
       }

       if(ecseat == "E")
       {
           ecsi = 4;
       }
       if(ecseat == "F")
       {
           ecsi = 5;
       }


       flight[ecrow-1][ecsi] = 'X';

       cout << "Displaying Updated Flight Seating Chart" << endl;

       return display();
   }

   if(type != 1 && type != 2 && type !=3)
   {
       cout << "Error" << endl;
       cout << "The Ticket Type Selected does not exist." << endl;
       cout << "Exiting Program" << endl;
       cout << ". . . . . . . ." << endl;
       exit(13);
       return(13);
   }

}

//This function allows the user to cancel their seat selection.
int cancel()
{

   int canrow;
   string canseat;

   cout << "We are sorry you wish to cancel your seat assignment." << endl;
   cout << "Please enter the row of your seat (1-13)." << endl;

   cin >> canrow;

   cout << "Please enter the seat letter (A-F)." << endl;

   cin >> canseat;

   cout << "You selected Row " << canrow << " Seat " << canseat << endl;

   int canseati;

   if(canseat == "A")
   {
       canseati = 0;
   }

   if(canseat == "B")
   {
       canseati = 1;
   }

   if(canseat == "C")
   {
       canseati = 2;
   }

   if(canseat == "D")
   {
       canseati = 3;
   }

   if(canseat == "E")
   {
       canseati = 4;
   }

   if(canseat == "F")
   {
       canseati = 5;
   }

   flight[canrow-1][canseati] = '*';

   return display();

}

//This function allows the user to exit the program.
int close()
{
   cout << "Exiting Program" << endl;
   cout << ". . . . . . . ." << endl;
   exit(11);
   return(11);
}

//This starts the main program/menu used to run the functions.
int main()

{

   int z = 0;

   do
   {
       //These for loops fill the flight array with '*' to show all seats as empty.
       for(int a = 0; a < rows; a++)
       {
           for(int b = 0; b < seats; b++)
           {
               flight[a][b] = '*';
           }
       }

       z = z+1;

   }while (z = 0);

   //This creates the LCV and sets it equal to 0 to run the do loop.
   int x = 0;

   do
   {
       //These four lines explain what the program does to the user.
       cout << "Welcome to Flight Seat Assigner" << endl;
       cout << "This program will allow you to select an available seat for your flight" << endl;
       cout << "based on the ticket type and available seats." << endl;
       cout << "You also can cancel a seat assignment or display the seating chart." << endl;

       //This line tells the user to pick a menu option.
       cout << "Please select from the following menu to begin." << endl;

       //These lines tell the user what the menu options are.
       cout << "1. Display Flight Seating Assignments" << endl;
       cout << "2. Select a Seat" << endl;
       cout << "3. Cancel a Seating Assignment" << endl;
       cout << "4. Exit Program" << endl;

       //This creates a variable to store the user's menu selection.
       int menu = 0;

       //This stores the user's selected menu option.
       cin >> menu;

       //This if statement runs if the user selects the first menu option.
       if(menu == 1)
       {
           //This line runs the display function.
           return display();

       }

       //This if statement runs if the user selects the second menu option.
       if(menu == 2)
       {
           //This line runs the assign funciton.
           return assign();

       }

       //This if statement runs if the user selects the third menu option.
       if(menu == 3)
       {
           //This line runs the cancel function.
           return cancel();

       }

       //This if statement runs if the user selects the fourth menu option.
       if(menu == 4)
       {
           //This line runs the close function.
           return close();

       }

       //This else statement runs if the user enters a non-menu option.
       else
       {
           //These lines explain the user's meu selection mistake and closes the program.
           cout << "Error" << endl;
           cout << "The option selected does not exist." << endl;
           cout << "Please enter a number between 1-4 when using the menu." << endl;
           cout << "Closing Program" << endl;
           cout << ". . . . . . . ." << endl;
           exit (12);
           return(12);
       }

   //This while statement controls when the do loop runs.    
   }while (x = 0 && x != 0);


}
```

**Here is the code just for the do-while loop in question.**

```
    do
    {
        //These four lines explain what the program does to the user.
        cout << "Welcome to Flight Seat Assigner" << endl;
        cout << "This program will allow you to select an available seat for your flight" << endl;
        cout << "based on the ticket type and available seats." << endl;
        cout << "You also can cancel a seat assignment or display the seating chart." << endl;

        //This line tells the user to pick a menu option.
        cout << "Please select from the following menu to begin." << endl;

        //These lines tell the user what the menu options are.
        cout << "1. Display Flight Seating Assignments" << endl;
        cout << "2. Select a Seat" << endl;
        cout << "3. Cancel a Seating Assignment" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit Program" << endl;

        //This creates a variable to store the user's menu selection.
        int menu = 0;

        //This stores the user's selected menu option.
        cin >> menu;

        //This if statement runs if the user selects the first menu option.
        if(menu == 1)
        {
            //This line runs the display function.
            return display();

        }

        //This if statement runs if the user selects the second menu option.
        if(menu == 2)
        {
            //This line runs the assign funciton.
            return assign();

        }

        //This if statement runs if the user selects the third menu option.
        if(menu == 3)
        {
            //This line runs the cancel function.
            return cancel();

        }

        //This if statement runs if the user selects the fourth menu option.
        if(menu == 4)
        {
            //This line runs the close function.
            return close();

        }

        //This else statement runs if the user enters a non-menu option.
        else
        {
            //These lines explain the user's meu selection mistake and closes the program.
            cout << "Error" << endl;
            cout << "The option selected does not exist." << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a number between 1-4 when using the menu." << endl;
            cout << "Closing Program" << endl;
            cout << ". . . . . . . ." << endl;
            exit (12);
            return(12);
        }

    //This while statement controls when the do loop runs.    
    }while (x = 0 && x != 0);
```

Sorry the code is so long, but the program is almost finished. I just need to fix the loop not restarting as far as I can tell.

Comment: The error is quite obvious here, but in the future please make a [mre]. This means you need to post a **full program** which also doesn't contain any irrelevant code. The second block of code you posted is not a [mre] because it is not a full program and it contains irrelevant things such as the code printing the menu.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what `return` does. Why do all of your functions return `int` when they should return `void`? You declared your `display` function to return `int` but you never return anything causing undefined behavior. Also enable your compiler warnings. You have a common assignment-in-condition bug which good compilers can warn about.

Comment: `}while (x = 0 && x != 0);`

What's your intention here? Because that makes no sense at all. If I understood what you were trying to do I offer a suggestion, but at the moment I have no idea.

Comment: One problem (among many) is that if you don't want a function to exit, then don't use return. `return display();` or `return assign();` for example will cause your `main` function to exit and your program to end. It's clear you don't understand `return`, it seems you'd be closer to a correct program if you just deleted `return` from your code.

Comment: `exit (12);
            return(12);` You realise that `exit` exits your program? So there is absolutely no point in having any code after a call to `exit`.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess here because I don't know the history of this program. But it looks to me that originally this code was a lot better than it is now, with only a few errors. But then the compiler has warned you about various parts of your code and you've tried to improve it by taking the compilers suggestions too literally. So the compiler has (for instance) warned you about missing return statements so you've added a return statement, when what you should have done was make the function a void function, so it doesn't need a return statement.

Comment: Do you see? The compiler doesn't know what you are trying to do, so although you should pay attention to it, and fix any issues it mentions, you can't just slavishly do what it says without thinking for yourself about what the real probem is.

Answer (score 0):

BessieTheCow's comment led me to the correct solution for the program. I changed the functions to void and removed the returns for the most part. Now the program works great. Thank you for all of your help everyone. It is much appreciated by this programming noob.